# Linux Kernel -- what happens after fork() creates the child process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fork, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am wondering what happen after `do_fork()` finishes creating the child process and calls `wake_up_new_task()` on it?

What happens before the child process starts executing? and where is the entry point for the new process?

In my question I am asking about functions and code in the Linux kernel the newly forked process must go through until it starts executing. For example, I know it has to go thought `ret_from_fork()` assembly code in `entry_64.S`. It also goes through `schedule_tail`. But what else? Can someone give me the complete picture?

Thanks.

Comment: *"Use the Source, Luke!"*  There are no secrets in Linux.  Just download a source-package if you haven't already done so. The forked process, like its parent, will appear to "return from the `fork()` call, but with a different return-code than the parent receives.  (That, of course, is how the child knows it's a child, and vice-versa.)

Comment: @MikeRobinson . I totally agree! I have been playing with this for a while. But what I have got so far is a bunch of disconnected islands of understanding. I know the some of the "stops" the process must go through, but I do not have the complete picture. I want to link these islands so I can fix the bug I am working on right now. Also, my question goes far beyond what you mentioned "will appear to return...." I am asking about actual assembly and c code in the Linux kernel.

Comment: Then perhaps you should open a different question which talks about what *really* concerns you, namely:  "the bug you are working-on right now!"  Perhaps this question is an example of what's called an "XY Problem."

Comment: @MikeRobinson .... well, I would like to understand the complete picture first and fix the bug myself first. If that does not work, I will describe my problem and ask people for clues.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I think this is what I was looking for: http://www.quora.com/Linux-Kernel/After-a-fork-where-exactly-does-the-childs-execution-start

Comment: Good luck with that, Hebbo.  (And, I more or less feel the same way about such things ...)  Nevertheless, there's one *very* important thing to keep in mind (FYI ...) whenever you're working with forums like this one:  "If you describe the problem that you are facing, *only* in terms of 'the herring that you are now chasing,'" then everybody else in the world can only assist you in 'chasing *that* herring.'  They can't tell you whether the aforesaid herring is *red* or not.  (Quite likely ...) there are many-someones, out here in the REST of the world, who have "been there, done that." :-)